volume of linear isoparametric pyramid element by integral transformation
Given are the 5 nodal coordinates $\underline{\underline{nodes}}$ in the real space $\underline{x}=[x,y,z]$ of an isogeometric linear  pyramid element. The base of the pyramid is a quadrilateral which must not necessarily be planar.
I want to compute the volume of that pyramid by making use of the isogeometric shape functions.
The shape functions and their derivatives are given by
$$
\underline{N}(r,s,t)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 (1-r)(1-s)(1-t) \\
 r(1-s)(1-t) \\
 rs(1-t) \\
 (1-r) s (1-t) \\
 t \\
\end{bmatrix}
~~,~~
\underline{\underline{dN}} = \frac{\partial \underline{N}(r,s,t)}{\partial [r,s,t]}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 -(1-s)(1-t) & -(1-r)(1-t) & -(1-r)(1-s) \\
  (1-s)(1-t) & -r(1-t) &  -r(1-s) \\
 s(1-t) &  r(1-t) & -rs \\
 -s (1-t) &  (1-r) (1-t) &  -(1-r) s  \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
whereas the reference pyramid in the local space $(r,s,t)$ is defined by
$$
P_R = \{0\leq t\leq1 , 0 \leq r,s \leq 1-t \} ~.
$$
For computing the volume integral I have to evaluate
$$
V = \int_P 1 dx dy dz ~.
$$
By use of the shape functions (isoparametric concept) I can express the $x,y,z$-coordinates of my pyramid in the real space by the local $r,s,t$-coordinates via
$$
\underline{x}(r,s,t) = \underline{N}^T(r,s,t) \cdot \underline{\underline{nodes}}
$$
and hence shift the integral domain to the reference domain via
$$
V = \int_P 1 dx dy dz = \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-t} \int_0^{1-t} \det(\underline{\underline{J}}) dr ds dt
$$
where $\underline{\underline{J}}$ is the Jacobian of the isoparametric mapping.
If we choose the most simple case (the Pyramid $P$ being the reference pyramid itself in the real space) with
$$
\underline{\underline{nodes}} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0\\
 1 & 0 & 0\\
 1 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
~~,~~
\underline{\underline{J}}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
(s + (1-s))(1-t) & 0 & 0\\
0 &  (r + (1-r))(1-t) & 0 \\
-r(s + (1-s)) & -s(r + (1-r)) & 1
\end{bmatrix}
~~\text{and}~~
\det(\underline{\underline{J}}) = (1-t)^2
$$
the integral becomes
$$
V 
= \int_P 1 dx dy dz 
= \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-t} \int_0^{1-t} (1-t)^2 dr ds dt
~.
$$
Now, comes the problem:
If I evaluate this integral I get
$$
\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-t} \int_0^{1-t} (1-t)^2 dr ds dt = \frac{1}{5} ~.
$$
This is not correct.
Since
$$
V = \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-z} \int_0^{1-z} 1 dx dy dz = \frac{1}{3} \neq \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-t} \int_0^{1-t} (1-t)^2 dr ds dt~.
$$
Why is that?
I understand, that the linear shape functions of the pyramid element entail a non-constant metric region since $\det(\underline{\underline{J}})\neq const.$ for the reference pyramid. I found some numerical integration formulas by Felippa, that give the correct results. However, I do not understand how these formulas are derived and why this above sketched general procedure of transforming the integral limits does not work.
There are also sources that suggest to use non-linear shape functions (link) that entail a constant metric region.
But why is the integral limit transform dependent on the choice of the shape functions?

I found my error: the integration limits are wrong. In the reference space we have $P_R = { 0 \leq, r,s,t \leq 1}$ such that $V = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-z}\int_{0}^{1-z}  1 dx dy dz = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} [1-t]^2 dr ds dt = 1/3$.
